# R script to arguments

Tags: r, rscript, openxlsx

currently, in this code below, there is manual intervention I want to define the path of 2 input files. but then I am not sure how to do it

```
library("openxlsx")
nm=readline("Enter  data file name:")                
readline("Enter input file name: (Press Enter)")        
input_file=read.xlsx(file.choose())
```

I want to add paths to line 3,4 to arguments so far I have tried this but it isn't correct

```
library("openxlsx")
args = commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)
nm=C:\Program Files\R-3.5.2\bin\tdd_data.xlsx
input_file=C:\Program Files\R-3.5.2\bin\tdd_rinput.xlsx
```

when I execute the code it gives me an error

```
***Error in source("tddarg.r") : tddarg.r:5:6: unexpected '/'
4: args = commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)
5: nm=C:/***
```

Comment: `nm <- args[1]; input_file=read.xlsx(args[2])` ? converting a line to argument doesn't make much sense so I can just try to guess what you're aiming for.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper i am trying to convert 
nm=readline("Enter  data file name:")                
readline("Enter input file name: (Press Enter)")        
input_file=read.xlsx(file.choose())
to arguments but i dont really know how to do it

Comment: You said that already, but I told you converting a line to an argument doesn't make sense, can you rephrase your question ?

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper please check :)

Comment: Thanks, why doesn't my suggestion in my first comment work ?

Comment: oh, your just forgot double quotes: `nm="C:\Program Files\R-3.5.2\bin\tdd_data.xlsx"`, and `input_file="C:\Program Files\R-3.5.2\bin\tdd_rinput.xlsx"`

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper thanks man it worked fine :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make some changes and get exactly what you want.

```
nm="C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.2/bin/tdd_data1.xlsx"              
input_file=read.xlsx("C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.2/bin/tdd_rinput2.xlsx")
```

I've only changed the slashes and added the read function to it.